# Storing multiple customers

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a custom technical support tracking database in sql server.  I am familiar with Access and can't shake the multivalued column out of my head.  I have searched over and over and can only find that the solution would be a many to many relationship but I can't quite work that out, so I am coming here for help.

tblTask

| Column Name | Data Type | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TaskID | int | Primary key, identity specification = yes |
| TaskName | nchar(100) |  |
| TaskDescription | nchar(255) |  |
| CustomerID | int | Foreign Key goes back to Customer Table |

Most of the time there will be only one customer in a tblTask entry.  However, there are some instances where multiple customers are requesting assistance in one task.  How do I store that information?  Do I need to create another table?  Please help the uninitiated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship between tasks and customers is usually modeled with an association table, where the primary key is a composite key consisting of the PK from both tables (identifying relationship).

Below is an example including the customers table you presumably have. I suggest using `nvarchar` instead of `nchar` for variable-length character data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblTask(
      TaskID int IDENTITY NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_tblTask PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , TaskName nvarchar(100)    
    , TaskDescription nvarchar(255) 
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCustomer(
      CustomerID int IDENTITY NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , CustomerName nvarchar(100)    
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblTaskCustomer(
      TaskID    int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_tblTaskCustomer_tblTask FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblTask(TaskID)
    , CustomerID    int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_tblTaskCustomer_tblCustomer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblCustomer(CustomerID)
    --include other attributes relevant for this customer's association with the task
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tblTaskCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TaskID, CustomerID)
);
```

If you often query tasks associated with customers, you probably want a non-clustered index (or unique constraint) on CustomerID and TaskID (in that order) to help optimize those queries.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_tblTaskCustomer_CustomerID_TaskID 
    ON dbo.tblTaskCustomer(CustomerID, TaskID);
```

Comment: thanks.  i'm a little slow so once i mapped it out, mind. blown.